# Map<String,String> Dart equivalent in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to find an equivalent to `Map<String, String>` in Dart, but usable in Typescript. This is a quick way to define a string:string key:value store.

Also, this can be used like this, which is my next question:

`Map<String, List<String>>`

This would define a key:value store where the keys are strings and the values are a list of strings.

Is there any way to do either in Typescript?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If keys are just strings, you probably would prefer to use plain objects in TypeScript, which you can type as `Record<string, string>`.
[Example usage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20myMap%3A%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0AmyMap%5B%22foo%22%5D%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%0D%0AmyMap%5B%22bar%22%5D%20%3D%20%222%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyMap%5B%22foo%22%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%221%22%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0AmyMap.foo%20%3D%3D%3D%20%221%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20can%20use%20both%20syntaxes%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20shorterMap%3A%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20%221%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%222%22%0D%0A%7D%20%2F%2F%20much%20nicer%20syntax%20for%20initialization.)

Answer (score 31):

The Typescript equivalent would be:

```
const m = new Map<string, string[]>();
m.set("fruit", ["apple", "banana"]);
```

Note that `string[]` is the type "array of strings", which despite the name is a dynamically growable list of strings (unlike the fixed length arrays in many popular statically typed languages).

You can say `Array<string>` instead but this is probably less widely used.

If your key is a string, you may find it more convenient to use a JS object. Objects in JS are basically maps with string keys. In TS the example becomes:

```
type StringToArrayOfStrings = { 
    [name: string]: string[] 
};

const m: StringToArrayOfStrings = {};
m["fruit"] = ["apple", "banana"];
```

In the `type` declaration we state the signature of the indexing operator `[...]`. (It's possible to have numeric keys as well as string ones.)

**UPDATE**

Still using a plain object as a map, note that we don't have to use a `type` declaration to give a name to a type. The type declaration can be substituted in-place, and we can then immediately initialise `m` with a compatible object:

```
const m: { [name: string]: string[] } = {
    "fruit": ["apple", "banana"],
    "spaceship": ["orion", "apollo"]
};
```

Note that if we omit the type annotation on `m`:

```
const m = {
    "fruit": ["apple", "banana"],
    "spaceship": ["orion", "apollo"]
};
```

then the type of `m` is inferred to be more restrictive:

```
{
    fruit: string[];
    spaceship: string[];
}
```

the compiler will assume we mean that `m` is permanently stuck with just two properties, `fruit` and `spaceship`, and will not allow us to add more. Interestingly, it will not assume anything about the length of the arrays (even it is possible to describe such things in TS via tuple types).

Comment: Thank you. In Dart you can do `Map<String,String> myMap = {"key":"value"}` and it will type check appropriately. Is there a way to define the type inline like this in Typescript? My first attempt was `const myMap: {string: string} = {key: "value"}` And I'm sure you know how that went. 

Comment: Could you please explain what the significance of "name" is in `{ [name: string]: string[] }` and if it can be another value?

Comment: It can be any identifier, it’s purely to give us a way to document what the items are indexed by.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript, which has a [built-in Map class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). This can take any key/value pair, including `String, List<String>`. Well, there's no `List` type in JS, but you can use `Array` instead.